# KeyError from pandas DataFrame groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

This is a very strange error, I got `KeyError` when doing pandas DataFrame `groupby` for no obvious reason.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.tail(5)

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 165 entries, 0 to 164
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Id     165 non-null object
Time    165 non-null object
Val     165 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 3.9+ KB

df.columns
Index([u'Id', u'Time', u'Val'], dtype='object')

df.groupby(['Id'])
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-bba5c2dc5f75> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby(['Id'])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, **kwargs)
   3776         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
   3777                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze,
-> 3778                        **kwargs)
...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3288 
   3289             if not isnull(item):
-> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3291             else:
   3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'Id'
```

Note that, using `df.columns = df.columns.map(str.strip)` as suggested doesn't make any different -- I'm still getting the exact same output from `df.columns` and error as above:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(str.strip)
df.columns
Out[38]:
Index([u'Id', u'Time', u'Val'], dtype='object')
```

If there is anywhere that I can post this "test.csv", I can do it, because I am almost certain that the problem is the format of the file -- the "test.csv" is Windows based, and is output from SQL Server SSMS. This is very important, as I opened, copied & saved the exactly content using Notepad++, and there won't be such problem with the newly saved file.

Using `file test.csv` under Linux shows:

```
test.csv: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Here are the top several bytes from the file:

```
0000000 ef bb bf 49 64 2c 54 69 - 6d 65 2c 56 61 6c 0d 0a  Id,Time,Val..
0000020 54 35 31 31 35 2c 30 30 - 3a 30 30 3a 30 30 2c 32  T5115,00:00:00,2
0000040 30 2e 38 31 39 0d 0a 54 - 35 31 31 35 2c 30 30 3a  0.819..T5115,00:
0000060 30 30 3a 30 33 2c 31 36 - 2e 39 32 36 0d 0a 54 35  00:03,16.926..T5
0000100 31 31 35 2c 30 30 3a 30 - 30 3a 30 38 2c 31 31 2e  115,00:00:08,11.
0000120 33 34 33 0d 0a 54 35 31 - 31 35 2c 30 30 3a 30 30  343..T5115,00:00
0000140 3a 31 37 2c 36 2e 39 37 - 35 0d 0a 54 35 31 31 35  :17,6.975..T5115
0000160 2c 30 30 3a 30 30 3a 32 - 39 2c 31 33 2e 35 35 33  ,00:00:29,13.553
0000200 0d 0a 54 35 31 31 35 2c - 30 30 3a 30 30 3a 33 35  ..T5115,00:00:35
```

Any idea how to solve it? Thx.

Comment: You can try `df.columns = df.columns.map(str.strip)`

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks but that doesn't make any different. OP updated.

Answer (score 1):

[Line terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems) in Windows differ from other operating systems--in ASCII encoding, the newline character in Unix-like operating systems is `LF`, in Windows it's `CRLF`.  In order to maintain compatibility between systems, [Git allows the option](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#__code_core_autocrlf_code) to save files with the `CRLF` line ending in Windows and `LF` in other operating systems.  This is causing your problem--when `pandas.read_csv` runs on your file saved with SQL Server, it has the `CRLF` line endings and `pandas` interprets it as having an extra `CR` character at the end of every line.

Luckily for you, the `read_csv` function includes a parameter [lineterminator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which [you can set to `"\r"`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), the `CR` character, to have your lines read properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `lineterminator='\r'` won't work for me, as the  Ids will be read in as `\nT5119`. I've also tried `lineterminator='\r\n'`, but will get the error **`ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported`**

Answer (score 1):

Got to the bottom of it -- it is in fact that the Windows based csv files IS the root cause.

Proofs:

1. I opened, copied & saved the exactly content using Notepad++, and there won't be such problem with the newly saved file.
2. If I convert it using `dos2unix` under Linux, then try the above same code, it would work. The `groupby` will not threw exception any more.

Filed a bug at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16690

And the solution to it, if the pandas is earlier than 0.19, use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` in `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```